# Pandas Grouper calculate time elapsed between events

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to find the time elapsed between two events using Grouper but was unable to do so. Please help me out. Below is the i/p & expected o/p

**Input**

```
ID   Status           Datetime
A    Online     24/09/2017  7:00:00 AM
A    Offline    24/09/2017  7:30:00 AM     
A    Offline    24/09/2017  8:30:00 AM
A    Online     24/09/2017  9:30:00 AM
A    Offline    24/09/2017  10:00:00 AM
B    Offline    24/09/2017  6:00:00 AM
B    Online     24/09/2017  7:30:00 AM     
B    Online     24/09/2017  9:10:00 AM
B    Offline    24/09/2017  9:30:00 AM
B    Online     24/09/2017  9:40:00 AM
B    Offline    24/09/2017  10:00:00 AM
```

**Output**

```
ID        Hour_start                  Hour_end              Online_time
A    24/09/2017  7:00:00 AM     24/09/2017  8:00:00 AM          1800
A    24/09/2017  8:00:00 AM     24/09/2017  9:00:00 AM           0
A    24/09/2017  9:00:00 AM     24/09/2017  10:00:00 AM         1800
B    24/09/2017  6:00:00 AM     24/09/2017  7:00:00 AM           0
B    24/09/2017  7:00:00 AM     24/09/2017  8:00:00 AM          1800
B    24/09/2017  8:00:00 AM     24/09/2017  9:00:00 AM          3600
B    24/09/2017  9:00:00 AM     24/09/2017  10:00:00 AM         3000
```

**Using Pandas Grouper**

`df_output = df.groupby(['ID',pd.Grouper(key='Datetime', freq='H'),'status'])['event_time'].diff().dt.seconds.fillna(0)`

But this doesn't take into the condition of Online & Offline of the Status column

Please help me out. TIA

Comment: Whats the relationship between `Hour_start `,`Hour_end ` in your output and the `Datetime ` column in your initial df?

Comment: ```Hour_start``` & ```Hour_end``` are the one-hour intervals during which an ID exists. 
```Datetime``` is the timestamp of an ID's activity status(Online/Offline)

Comment: @wwnde do you need anything else? Could you help?

Comment: ok revert as soon as I can

Comment: Why is the first B in your output start time 7am and not 6am?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I removed it because it is not significant. Added it now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234508/discussion-between-nani-and-wwnde).

Comment: What's the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that *Datetime* column in your source DataFrame is of *datetime64* type.

My solution is based on 2-level grouping, first by *ID* and then (after some
intermediate operations) by hour.

Define 2 functions:

1. *onTimeById*, to compute *Online time* for each *ID* (the "external" grouping level):

   ```
   def onTimeById(grp):
       wrk = grp[grp.Status != grp.Status.shift()]
       wrk = wrk.set_index('Datetime').Status
       wrk = wrk.reindex(wrk.index.union(pd.date_range(wrk.index.min(),
           wrk.index.max(), freq='H'))).ffill()
       res = wrk.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='H')).apply(onTimeByHour)
       rv = res.iloc[:-1].reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'Hour_start',
           'Status': 'Online_time'})
       rv.insert(1, 'Hour_end', res.index[1:])
       return rv
   ```
2. *onTimeByHour*, to compute *Online time* for each *hour* (the "internal" grouping level):

   ```
   def onTimeByHour(grp2):
       if grp2.size > 1:
           dd = grp2.index.to_series().diff()
           rv = dd[grp2 == 'Offline'].sum().seconds
           if grp2.iloc[-1] == 'Online':
               rv += 3600 - dd.sum().seconds
           return rv
       return 0 if grp2.iloc[0] == 'Offline' else 3600
   ```

Then run:

```
res = df.groupby('ID').apply(onTimeById).reset_index(level=0).reset_index(drop=True)
```

The result, for your source data, is:

```
  ID          Hour_start            Hour_end  Online_time
0  A 2017-09-24 07:00:00 2017-09-24 08:00:00         1800
1  A 2017-09-24 08:00:00 2017-09-24 09:00:00            0
2  A 2017-09-24 09:00:00 2017-09-24 10:00:00         1800
3  B 2017-09-24 06:00:00 2017-09-24 07:00:00            0
4  B 2017-09-24 07:00:00 2017-09-24 08:00:00         1800
5  B 2017-09-24 08:00:00 2017-09-24 09:00:00         3600
6  B 2017-09-24 09:00:00 2017-09-24 10:00:00         3000
```

To understand all details how this solution works, save group "A" under
a variable, e.g. running:

```
gr = df.groupby('ID')
grp = gr.get_group('A')
```

Then execute each instruction from *onTimeById* and see the results.

Apply the same approach to trace how *onTimeByHour* works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was able to run this on a small dataset but on the main dataset I am getting an ```ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis```. I have duplicates on Datetime because it is not unique.

Comment: Probably your *Datetime* column contains non-unique dates / times for some *ID*.
Make sure you have unique dates / times for each *ID*.

Comment: Thanks. I removed duplicates and it worked. But, getting incorrect values when I cross-checked for a sample.
Any idea why?

Comment: Ask another question, with a sample of your data getting these incorrect values.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68291091/summarize-active-time-of-user-activity-log-data-in-hourly-buckets