# Summarize active time of user activity log data in hourly buckets

Tags: python, pandas, logging

I am trying to find the hourly active time of a user from the user activity data. Below is the sample i/p & o/p

**Input**

```
ID   Status           Datetime
A    Online     24/09/2017  7:00:00 AM
A    Offline    24/09/2017  7:30:00 AM     
A    Online     24/09/2017  9:30:00 AM
A    Offline    24/09/2017  10:00:00 AM
B    Online     24/09/2017  6:00:00 AM
B    Offline    24/09/2017  7:30:00 AM     
B    Online     24/09/2017  9:10:00 AM
B    Offline    24/09/2017  9:30:00 AM
B    Online     24/09/2017  9:40:00 AM
B    Offline    24/09/2017  10:00:00 AM
```

**Expected Output**

```
ID        Hour_start                  Hour_end              Online_time
A    24/09/2017  7:00:00 AM     24/09/2017  8:00:00 AM          1800
A    24/09/2017  8:00:00 AM     24/09/2017  9:00:00 AM           0
A    24/09/2017  9:00:00 AM     24/09/2017  10:00:00 AM         1800
B    24/09/2017  6:00:00 AM     24/09/2017  7:00:00 AM          3600
B    24/09/2017  7:00:00 AM     24/09/2017  8:00:00 AM          1800
B    24/09/2017  8:00:00 AM     24/09/2017  9:00:00 AM           0
B    24/09/2017  9:00:00 AM     24/09/2017  10:00:00 AM         2400
```

Please help me out. TIA

Answer (score 1):

My solution from [Pandas Grouper calculate time elapsed between events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68248400) gives **proper**
results also for this source data.

The result is:

```
  ID          Hour_start            Hour_end  Online_time
0  A 2017-09-24 07:00:00 2017-09-24 08:00:00         1800
1  A 2017-09-24 08:00:00 2017-09-24 09:00:00            0
2  A 2017-09-24 09:00:00 2017-09-24 10:00:00         1800
3  B 2017-09-24 06:00:00 2017-09-24 07:00:00         3600
4  B 2017-09-24 07:00:00 2017-09-24 08:00:00         1800
5  B 2017-09-24 08:00:00 2017-09-24 09:00:00            0
6  B 2017-09-24 09:00:00 2017-09-24 10:00:00         2400
```

Just as your expected result. So I don't see any error in my solution.

If you have any source data for which my solution gives wrong result,
add this data to your post.